# How do "you" pronounce eczema?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, silent-letters

### /ˈɛɡzɪmə/, /ˈɛksɪmə/, /ˈɛksmə/

As I no longer live in the UK I don't usually hear how *eczema* is pronounced, so I've always pronounced it as [ig-zee-muh](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eczema) but recently my English boyfriend told me that the *only* correct pronunciation is **ˈɛksmə** (the second e- is silent), and he's quite adamant about it!  He considers my pronunciation as nothing short of an abomination. Listen to the first British speaker on [Forvo](http://www.forvo.com/word/eczema/#en) to  hear the "correct" pronunciation of eczema.

However, when I checked online I saw that there are three ways of pronouncing this term.

I would like to know which pronunciation is most dominant in British English and in American English. And why the second e- is sometimes silent in eckz(e)ma.

Comment: I have never heard a two-syllable version of it. Whether the cluster is voiced depends on the speaker and sometimes the utterance.

Comment: In Britain it has two syllables *exma* (I don't understand the phonetic alphabet). It sounds as if your boy friend is absolutely right. I listened to those specimens which you linked and clearly Americans give it three syllables *ex-e-ma*.

Comment: Perhaps that is a British vs. American English issue. I've always heard three syllables in the U.S. Though the stress is very slight, I think U.S. English speakers would hear 3 syllables.

Comment: I personally vacillate between [ˈεɡzəmə] and [εɡˈziːmə], I think. Though I’m fairly certain if someone I was talking to consistently said [ˈεks(ə)mə], I’d probably just say it the same way without really thinking. Your boyfriend is certainly not correct under any circumstances that any pronunciation other than [ˈεksmə] is incorrect or an abomination. It may be less common, but it occurs as an established pronunciation in a decent-sized chunk of the population, so you can’t just rule it out as ‘incorrect’.

Comment: Roughly, "ex-seh-muh".  And this is similar to how I've heard it pronounced on TV (in those "nightmare of psoriasis" ads, etc).  (US Midwest)

Comment: @tchrist: It's just not a word you actually *hear* all that often, but if I heard someone use three syllables my first thought would be they simply haven't heard it *enough*, so they're being unduly influenced by the spelling. Until now it would never have occurred to me that Americans routinely go out of their way to "voice" the middle bit. To me, that's almost on a par with reading *Xmas* out as *eck-su-mus* (plenty of people say *ecks-mus* in that context, rather than *kris-mus*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That wasn't what I meant by voice. Voicing is the distinction between /ks/ and /gz/.  And yes, it always has three syllables here. It sounds like somebody using only two syllables simply hasn’t heard it said enough.  Every physician I’ve heard say it has certainly used three syllables, including dermatologists.

Comment: A few examples from advertising: http://www.omnilexica.com/pronunciation/?q=eczema#.VRWsR6mCOK0

Comment: @tchrist: oic. Well it seems to me "voiced" /z/ there pretty much amounts to adding a neutral vowel which could be heard as another syllable. But I'm with WS2 re the "in Britain" bit.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, there is no reason to think that a voiced /z/ must add a new syllable. *Cosmos* certainly does not have three syllables, nor has *osmotic* four!

Comment: @Fumble For the voiced variety, just imagine you’re saying, “Eggs, ma!” (but with a shorter _a_ at the end, obviously).

Comment: I pronounce it like "eggs Emma". That's what I've heard, that's what I go with. On the other hand, it's a word that almost never comes up in conversation, so I can't say how standard my pronunciation is (I'm from the U.S., in case there turns out to be a difference between dialects).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh right, you probably think *medicine* and *secretary* have two syllables too. I mean *sylbles*. ;-)

Comment: I use 1 and 2 but never #3.

Comment: (Middle-aged) British English speaker living in London, never ever heard any pronunciation other than "exma" and that is how I say it. Then I probably haven't listened to US TV programmes in which people talk about it.

Comment: I'm Australian and the Macquarie Dictionary lists it as /ˈɛksəmə/. I have heard it said as /ˈɛksmə/ but the same person also says Saturday as /sætdeɪ/. I'll have to ask some people I know who speak well how they pronounce it now!

Comment: @tchrist: I think I use the 2- and 3-syllable versions of *medicine* about equally often - but curiously, in *that* case I associate the shorter one with "better educated, middle class". I *think* I don't often reduce *secretary* to only 2 syllables, but I suppose it's feasible I do it a lot without thinking, in rapid speech. I certainly wouldn't be likely to come out with the **4** syllable version, even when speaking slowly/loudly/carefully to people with hearing difficulties (sadly, an increasingly numerous category in my personal circle :).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Dropping any syllables from either word sounds weird over here. People expect *medicine* and *secretary* to be three and four syllables respectively.

Comment: @tchrist: Well, I've said it before here on ELU. It seems to me although AmE often appears more "advanced" than BrE (because of Webster's influence on orthography), in most other areas (syntax, pronunciation, etc.) it actually seems relatively "conservative". Particularly over the past 2-3 decades, the average Brit's exposure to dialectal and other variation has probably been far higher than the average American (we have very high immigration, and regional dialects are now *encouraged* rather than suppressed by national broadcasters, for example). Plus we have a *lot* of dialectal variation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So this is a left-right pond difference. It is often the case that unstressed schwa syllables are elided altogether (Presumably the second 'e' in 'eczema' was historically there on purpose because it was pronounced). It just turns out that the subtle stress in AmE vs BrE leads to keeping it in AmE and dropping it in BrE. Your 'medicine' example sounds very similar (the first 'i' is never dropped in AmE).

Comment: @FumbleFingers There are several factors at work here. One is a greater tendency in the British Isles to regress the stress to earlier syllables than here: *adult, croissant, ballet, beret, brochure, buffet, salon, vaccine, chalet, debris, garage, controversy, innovative, advertisement*. But *altimeter,  cigarette, magazine, renaissance, mustache* are counterexamples we stress earlier than you. Another may be a consequent or incidental tendency over yonder to further reduce unstressed syllables (*python* and *photon* don’t reduce here), even unto oblivion as in your *medcine* and *secretry*.

Comment: (Native AmE) ECK-suh-muh.

Comment: @tchrist: I thought [we specifically *sent* the Monty Python team over to you](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084352/) decades ago to teach you how to reduce the second syllable in *Python* to a schwa! As for our tendency to move stress to the first syllable - that precisely illustrates my point. Americans conservatively stick to *French* intonation, where Brits are quicker to complete the process of "anglicising" our speech (even though we fell behind on the orthography).

Comment: I've checked with someone who speaks well and they pronounce it as /ˈɛksəmə/ (ek-sa-ma). The person I quoted earlier speaks in a lower register which is why they drop the middle "e". Americans _tend_ to be more precise in their pronunciation. _Some_ British and Australians can be laxer, resulting in a schwa disappearing from some words, as in this case.

Comment: Medicine should be pronounced with as many syllables as medical. 'Medication' is another good clue. Cover the word, start revealing the letters, and pronounce them. When you see "medi-" and don't know what will come next, you have to commit to a pronunciation. You can't take it back a few letters later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just took an unscientific poll of North American professional actors (read: searched the web for `eczema commercial`), and "egzema" /ˈɛɡzɪmə/ was the most common, followed by the similar "eksema" /ˈɛksɪmə/. I hadn't heard "egzeema" /ɪɡˈzi:mə/ until today.

- A [TV ad for Elidel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDyYNMrTbnc) (pimecrolimus) cream 1% calls it a prescription drug to treat "egzema".
- Another Elidel ad [with an animated character](http://adland.tv/commercials/elidel-eczema-2004-060-usa) also says "egzema".
- A commercial for [Gold Bond](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uy3WiccJFv8) opens with a woman talking about "an eksema flareup" but it's kind of close. The voiceover says "egzema relief cream".
- "There are better ways to soothe egzeema" than spreading [ice cream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmuMqdUGHPM) all over your skin. "Try Polysporin egzeema essentials".
- "[Cortizone-10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtPP29YJJTM) intensive healing egzema lotion"
- [Neosporin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9iLkxEgz0I) because "Americans suffer from eksema"

The "egzema" and "eksema" pronunciations represent a common phonological process called *voicing assimilation*: "egzema" and "egzeema" are anticipatory while "eksema" is lag.

Comment: I took the liberty of tweaking your (non-IPA) phonetic writing a bit to make it less ambiguous and standardised, since ⟨ggs⟩ could mislead people to think you were talking about an unvoiced [s] and ⟨x⟩ can be pronounced either [gz] or [ks], obscuring the difference.

Answer (score 11):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eczema) and my own personal experience with American English suggest pronouncing it **ˈeg-zə-mə**

[Cambridge Dictionary Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/british/eczema) lists the pronunciation as **ˈek.sɪ.mə** and provides audio of English and American pronunciation.

Comment: +1 Concerning personal experience with dishydrotic eczema, I've heard it pronounced more phonetically, **ek.zɪ.mə**, a cross between the two pronunciations you provided.

Comment: @PaulRowe I disbelieve. It is not really possible to get a clean, unvoiced /k/ if you have a vowel before and a voiced consonant following. Your glottis just isn’t up to the task.

Comment: @tchrist, Juǀ'hoan would like to disagree with you on that

Comment: Here in New York, I say EGG-zih-muh, much like the first IPA rendering at top.  I imagine that these other testimonies prove that in other places people say it differently, but I've never heard it any other way, least of all condensed into two syllables.

Comment: @Darkgamma I was referring to Paul Rowe’s glottis, not to Jul’hoan’s. :)

Comment: @tchrist I shouldn’t like to presume anything about Paul Rowe’s glottis, but the sequence /kz/ is not that difficult to produce audibly distinctly from /gz/. I’m sure _Mark Zuckerberg_, for example, would be annoyed to hear he was really called _Marg_ or _Suckerberg_. There’s bound to be _some_ voicing spillover, of course, so the last bit of the /k/ will be a bit voiced or the /z/ will only start getting voiced halfway through—but that’s still enough to distinguish it from the fully voiced /gz/, where voicing never stops. And of course the length of the /ε/ is a major clue to voicedness, too.

Comment: @tchrist I've seen it mentioned here at ELU and, I think, also on ELL, that native English speakers are pretty competent with a variety of sound combinations. (We have some frustrations with certain combinations at the beginning of the word, which is probably why the first letter isn't pronounced in certain words like psychology, gnome, and mnemonic.) If we can properly enunciate "strike zone" and "pizza", both having an unvoiced consonant sound followed by a voiced fricative, we can pronounce eczema phonetically.

Comment: @PaulRowe Pretty sure that *pizza* has no voiced consonants.  I say it like *Pete’s* before the schwa, so just /ts/ there, no /z/ at all. I thought everyone did.

Comment: @tchrist Heh... It sounds like we're getting into the different shortcuts different people take when pronouncing particular combinations, much like I used to use a "ch" sound at the beginning of "track" and "truck" and such.

Comment: I (in the US) agree with your Merriam-Webster.  I learned this word as a child from a TV commercial about such horrors as "eczema, seborrhea, psoriasis".  I didn't know what they were, but they were fun to say.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to check here: http://youglish.com/search/eczema

The cons: it doesn’t indicate the location of the speakers.
The pros: they are professional speakers.

They added accent support.

Comment: Super link! The speakers' accents are a good indication of regionality and nationality.

Comment: It's a brilliant website and although the accent support is not perfect, a few American pronunciations were included as British, it's most spot on. :)

Comment: That's an amazing site, never seen it before! I'd pronounce it like this: https://youglish.com/getcid/6506615/eczema - although my form of BrE is completely different to Paxman's

Answer (score 3):

ˈɛksɪmə.  I am a U.S. native (Chicago).  I have also commonly heard ˈɛɡzɪmə, but never ˈɛksmə, as far as I can recall.

These were the only pronunciations I was familiar with till I was surprised years ago to learn that the skin cream Noxzema, pronounced nɒkˈsiːmə (nok-SEE-ma) and sold under that name for nearly a century, was so named because it was advertised as a treatment for eczema.  That is, the name of the cream assumes a pronunciation of ɛkˈsiːmə (ek-SEE-ma) or ɛɡˈziːmə (eg-ZEE-ma) for the word eczema.  Prior to hearing this bit of information, I had never heard this pronunciation for eczema.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noxzema

Answer (score 2):

I'm a lifelong US resident and the daughter of a dermatologist.  I grew up hearing my father pronounce it ig-**zee**-muh.  He grew up in Chicago and did his residency at the Mayo Clinic in Minnesota.  However, he moved us to North Carolina when I was a baby.  So though I always said "ig-**zee**-muh" (accent on second syllable, long e) I recall most locals saying "**egg**-ze-muh" (accent on first syllable, pronounced like the word "egg", second e more of a schwa).  I've never, ever heard the word spoken as only two syllables.